EF Core SaveChanges in transaction context
This may be a stupid question, but I am really struggling here.
I am trying to write some business logic in a service method. And this service method calls multiple database operations in a data access layer classes.
And within each data access method I am calling dbcontext.SaveChanges() method.
But I am expecting to rollback all the changes if the code breaks as it is the usual database behavior. But the changes are committed to the database. What am I missing?
I am using EF Core 7 and the Pomelo provider.
Also please note that this is a blazor server application. And the dbcontext is registered as a scoped service.
public async Task<RevisionDTO> UpdateRevisionByRevisionDTO(RevisionDTO revisionDTO)
{
    var document = documentsRepository.GetDocumentByDocNumber(revisionDTO.DocumentNumber);
    var revisions = documentDetailsRepository.GetDocumentdetailsByrfDocuments(document.rfDocuments.GetValueOrDefault());
    var revision = revisions.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RevisionNo == revisionDTO.RevisionNumber);

    Documentdetails updatedRevision = new Documentdetails()
    {
        rfDocumentDetails = revision.rfDocumentDetails,
        rfDocuments = revision.rfDocuments,
        RevisionNo = revisionDTO.RevisionNumber,
        DateofIssue = revisionDTO.DateOfIssue,
        Description = revisionDTO.Description,
        AmendedBy = revisionDTO.AmendedBy,
        AuthorisedBy = revisionDTO.AuthorizedBy,
        AuthorisedDate = revisionDTO.AuthorizedDate,
    };

    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            documentDetailsRepository.UpdateDocumentDetails(updatedRevision, revision.rfDocumentDetails.GetValueOrDefault());
            await _logService.AddLog(LogsUtils.ActionType.Edit, document.DrawingNo, revisionDTO.RevisionNumber, "", LogsUtils.Category.Revision);
            historyTextService.UpdateHistoryText(revisionDTO.DocumentNumber);
            throw new Exception();
            transaction.Commit();
            return RevisionTransformer.ToDTO(updatedRevision);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw new Exception("Revision update failed.\n", ex);
        }
    }
}


How is the DbContext lifetime scoped within your application? Is this an MVC app with a container, or using a 3rd party container like Autofac, or spinning up new DbContexts when initializing the Repository vs. this class? If this class' DbContext (context) is not the same instance as the DbContext your repository is using, the Transaction won't be respected.


Do you observe exception that would result in rolback?
If last line RevisionTransformer.ToDTO(updatedRevision) throws, it's already commited.


Maybe you can try to comment the dbcontext.SaveChanges() from each data access method? According to this document, SaveChagnes() shall create a Save point.

Is the same context (i.e. that instance) used in all add/update methods? If not, or anyway, you can try to use a TransactionScope instead (but be aware that by default it has a higher isolation level).

@StevePy This is a blazor server app and the DbContext is registered  as scoped. Since I am using dependency injection it's the same context.

@MichałTurczyn no. No Exception is throwing from anywhere. though I am manually throwing an exception to test the rollback as you can see.

@TinyWang I actually didn't know EF core uses an implicit transaction for savechanged(). Thanks for the suggestion.

@GertArnold it's the same context. It's registered as a scoped service.

Thank you for your kind reply @Lash and do you have any other concerns in this question?

@TinyWang thank for the reply. I actually removed savechanges methods from the repository classes. And added it at the end of each in service methods. I didn't know about the Unit of work design pattern. But now I have another problem. Previously I saved the changes to the database thus creating autogenerated p.keys for a one table. And the next operation uses that PK to add a record to a table with foreign key constraint. Now since I have removed the savechanged from each repo method the second method cannot get the auto generated key from the first operation.

Sorry my bad, I didn't test it in my side and I just searched online and share the searching result.  I had a test in my side with codes below https://i.sstatic.net/kFABVJb8.png. And just like what you said, without _context.SaveChangesAsync(); I can't get the autogenerated Id from table 1, so that I can't add row to table 2. By the way, I didn't set value for adding item to table 2 so that I must get an exception. Based on my debug, I found that when I get the id successfully, in database, there's no new row in table 1, so that the rollback worked .

@TinyWang thanks for testing the code. This is a strange behavior. I referred the documentation and also some online tutorials. Everything suggests that savechanges() would not effect the rollback behavior. But in my code I can't rollback after a savechanges(). I need to dig more.

thank you for your confiramtion Lash, if you want to get help from SO, could you please creata a minimal sample reproducing the issue so that we could help troubleshoot?
